# Removing Particular Objects From a Legend

Tags: matlab, get, annotations, bar-chart, legend

I need your guys help in solving a small problem Im facing. When I want to depict f1 and f2 using bar function, I need to exclude f2 annotation objects in the legend tab of the figure, but the set syntax written below seems to give the error mentioned.

The code is as below:

```
f1= bar([SN, SN, SN], [Class_Work, Final_Exam, Shift_Grade'-Grade], K, 'stacked');

f2= bar([SN(idx), SN(idx), SN(idx)], [Class_Work(idx), Final_Exam(idx), SG(idx)-Grade(idx)], K*dy/dx, 'stacked', 'LineWidth', 2.5);  

set(f1,{'DisplayName'},{'Mid-Term','Final-Exam','Shift'}')
legend('location','NorthEast','Orientation','horizontal'); 

% in order to Exclude f2 indices from legend: (BUT SEEMS NOT WORKING based on error!)
set(get(get(f2,'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),...
    'IconDisplayStyle','off');
```

After running it gives this error in command-window including the correct figure, but with all annotation objects:

??? Error using ==> get

*Conversion to double from cell is not possible.*

Error in ==> set(get(get(f2,'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),...

**The Figure, which I need is that: *data4, data5, and data6* graphic objects (related to f2) in the legend tab NOT to appear, when drawing f2.**

I appreciate your helps in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special syntax to call legend which should help in your case. From Matlab documentation:

```
 legend(h, 'string1', 'string2', ...);
```

> displays a legend on the plot containing the objects identified by the handles in the vector h and uses the specified strings to label the corresponding graphics object (line, barseries, etc.).

So, in your case you just should do:

```
 legend(f1, 'Mid-Term', 'Final-Exam', 'Shift');
```

and then modify other properties of a legend (location, orientation, etc.) accordingly.

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, to make your initial code work, you should do:

```
 annots = get(h,'Annotation');
 for i=1:length(annots)
     set(get(annots{i},'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','off');
 end
```

`annots = get(h,'Annotation')` returns cell array and then you just operate on each cell (i.e. `annots{i}`) of this array.

Comment: I am aware of the legend syntax. The problem I have is that, I have 2 set of bars (f1 and f2), thus two legends. Therefore, I need to use the code below in order to force f2 legend's objects (i.e. 'data4', 'data5', and 'data6' to be NOT SHOWED in the legend bar.

Comment: The problem is with:                  set(get(get(f2,'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),...
                                                                                                        ?? Error using ==> get
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.                       HOW CAN I SOLVE THE SYNTAX FOR THIS LINE? PLS HELP :(

Comment: Well `get(h,'Annotation')` returns cell array, so you can do:  `annots = get(h,'Annotation'); for i=1:length(annots); set(get(annots{i},'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','off'); end;`

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked :-)  Could you just explain how you understand the syntax u used to convert the doubles to cells? couldnt one use num2cell?

Comment: However, as I understood you are trying to put two bar plots on the same figure, isn't it? Then you want a legend which would contain only entries for your first bar plot. I think in this case the syntax `legend(h,'string1','string2',...);` should help you.

Comment: Yes, but the fact is that, even if you do specify legend(h,'string1','string2'), if there is also a third string and you dont want it to be shown, it will still show it, so this syntax alone does not work. That is why you have to use get. Also an alternative to the syntax you use is set(f1,{'DisplayName'},{'Mid-Term','Final-Exam','Shift'}'), but with the same problem. Which the code you wrote in your 1st comment solves the problem :)

Comment: Hmm, it's strange. I just tried (Matlab 2009b) and it displays only the strings which I'm asking for (with `legend(h,'string1','string2',...)` syntax). Regarding your question about cells arrays: I didn't do any conversion. `annots = get(h,'Annotation')` returns cell array and then you just want to operate on each cell (i.e. `annots{i}`) of this array.